# Parsing Weather XML with Python

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I'm a beginner but with a lot of effort I'm trying to parse some data about the weather from an .xml file called "weather.xml" which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Weather>
<locality name="Rome" alt="21">
    <situation temperature="18°C" temperatureF="64,4°F" humidity="77%" pression="1016 mb" wind="5 SSW km/h" windKN="2,9 SSW kn">
        <description>clear sky</description>
        <lastUpdate>17:45</lastUpdate>
        />
    </situation>
    <sun sunrise="6:57" sunset="18:36" />
</locality>
```

I parsed some data from this XML and this is how my Python code looks now:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('weather.xml')

entry_situation = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('situation')
entry_locality = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('locality')

print entry_locality[0].attributes['name'].value
print "Temperature: "+entry_situation[0].attributes['temperature'].value
print "Humidity: "+entry_situation[0].attributes['humidity'].value
print "Pression: "+entry_situation[0].attributes['pression'].value
```

It's working fine but if I try to parse data from "description" or "lastUpdate" node with the same method, I get an error, so this way must be wrong for those nodes which actually I can see they are differents.

I'm also trying to write output into a log file with no success, the most I get is an empty file.

Thank you for your time reading this.

Comment: Closing </Weather> is missing. What '/>' is doing on line 7? Btw have you already looked at [lxml's objectify API](http://lxml.de/objectify.html)?

Comment: Closing </Weather> is missing because the file doesn't stop there but there is a part which I don't care to retrieve data from. I've read there but I don't understand how I may adapt the code for my usage. Trying to learn but not knowledge about Python at all, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because "description" and "lastUpdate" are not attributes but child nodes of the "situation" node.

Try:

```
d = entry_situation[0].getElementsByTagName("description")[0]
print "Description: %s" % d.firstChild.nodeValue
```

You should use the same method to access the "situation" node from its parent "locality".

By the way you should take a look at the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) module, especially the objectify API as yegorich said.  It is easier to use.

Comment: It worked this way and I say an huge thank you to you. It works for "description", if I add other code for "lastUpdate" it always show me only "lastUpdate" also in "description".

Comment: It shouldn't.  I get the right result by using

    `d = entry_situation[0].getElementsByTagName("description")[0]`
    `print "Description: %s" % d.firstChild.nodeValue`
    `l = entry_situation[0].getElementsByTagName("lastUpdate")[0]`
    `print "Last update: %s" % l.firstChild.nodeValue`

Comment: The output now is absolutely fine. What I want to achieve now is piping the "print" stuff to a file. I've tried directly from a shell using this command:    ./script.py > <filename>           It gave me some ASCII errors which I resolved by writing to the code "import codecs
import locale
import sys" and "sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter(locale.getpreferredencoding())(sys.stdout) ". It works but what I want to achieve is to append to a file, not always overwrite it. If I put some code to output the stream directly from .py it gives ASCII errors. I'd like to have TIMESTAMP + all "print" stuff

Comment: I did it! I print the output through a simple bash! Maybe it is not the "right way" but it did the trick. I also added the date and the time in the first print line. S. de Melo, thank you for your extreme patience!